# How to slideUp like an odometer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this, and it's "good enough", but my original vision was to have the numbers roll up like an odometer:

```
setTimeout(slideUp,2000);
function slideUp() {
   $('#odometer').slideUp('slow','swing',slideDown);
}
function slideDown() {
    $('#odometer').removeClass('highlight').slideDown('slow');
}
```

So what it does is: when the page loads, the number is highlighted.  Two seconds after the page loads, it slides up out of sight and then slides down in a normal font.

But what I'd like for it to do is count up to the number like an odometer.
I could give it a starting number as well, so that the user wouldn't have to watch
it count to an exorbitantly high number.

Comment: Maybe something like this? http://aghull.github.io/coding/2013/06/22/jQuery-odometer/

Comment: http://github.hubspot.com/odometer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may go and read the source code of [ScrollerJS](http://scrollerjs.pixelstech.net/). It does exactly what you want to achieve with both CSS transition and DOM animation support.

And most importantly it's open source and doesn't depend any third party libraries including jQuery, D3, Velocity etc.